# Regex for column separated values (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I have the following dataset, organized in columns:

```
startword:          blablabla:              blablabla:
123456              123456                  123456
important phrase 1  important phrase 2      important phrase 3
```

And I want to have the `important phrases` in different matches. At the moment, I have the following regex (which works fine, see [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wP9rD9/1)):

```
^startword:(?:.*\R){2}\K(?<important>.*)
# look for the startword, consume two non-important lines and throw it away (\K)
# capture everything from the important line to a group called "important"
```

**Expected** output (an array actually):

```
match1 => important phrase 1
match2 => important phrase 2
match3 => important phrase 3
```

At the moment, I split the line programmatically in `PHP` (using two spaces as delimiter), but I wonder if there's a better way to have the matches in groups directly (some `\G` magic ?).

Comment: show how should look the final output(result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this single regex to capture all your matches:

```
(?:^startword:(?:.*\R){2}\K|(?!^)\G\h{2,})(.+?(?=\h{2}|$))
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wP9rD9/3)

- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.
- Lookahead `(?=\h{2}|$)` makes sure that we have 2 or more horizontal white-spaces ahead or end of line is reached after our captured text.

Comment: Thanks a ton, brilliant as always :-)